Need clarification on httponly cookie restrictions on firebase functions (v2)

Note: I am using firebase functions "v2" (const functions = require('firebase-functions/v2'))

So, according to several sources, which I will list at the end, it seems as though the firebase functions will automatically remove all httponly cookies sent other than __session,
There seems to be no way to control the preflight OPTIONS request to enable httopnly cookies (Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true), since it seems that all OPTIONS requests (i.e. preflight requests) are tightly controlled by the firebase functions engine itself, and cannot be modified in the function defintiion functions.https.onRequest, as those only ever receive the POST/GET/PUT/DELETE request AFTER the preflight is handled.
What confuses me is, how is the __session cookie even sent under the hood by the official auth library for firebase? If I have the firebase function manually set the __session cookie as httponly, I have no way to send it back on the next request since if I use the fetch api with ``credentials: "include"`, it will always trigger the
Request blocked by CORS policy, resposne to preflight request sent Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: '' but Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: 'true' is required for this request
(NOT an exact quote, but close enough)
So in summary

Does anyone know how the firebase authentication client is sending the __session cookie under the hood if the preflight request does not allow Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true. Is it using instead non-httponly (js accessible) cookies and sending it in a manual "Cookie: " header from the fetch api or similar ajax?

If I want to implement custom authentication (e.g. custom jwt protocols), should I just migrate away from firebase functions. Should I consider google cloud functions directly (as opposed ot through the firebase ecosystem) or will they have the same restriction. Is it time to move to a vps server, or use NextJS and vercel?


Supporting info:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies
Why doesn't firebase auth support httponly cookie persistence?

Hi, First of all I'm no expert on the subject so I will just be sharing my opinion that to my limited knowledge is correct. So, please be lenient if this proves to be not useful.
I also think it is a good question to understand the secure authentication in Firebase. But any questions related to specific services should be asked to its relevant support department, that's probably the reason for the restriction. Check this out:

Why cant I ask customer service related questions


According to what I could find out on the internet, this is how the firebase handles the __session cookie:

Firebase's __session cookie is not subject to the same CORS restrictions as other cookies.

The Firebase Auth SDK handles the __session cookie internally. The SDK doesn't rely on the browser's normal cookie-sending mechanisms.

The Firebase Auth SDK reads the __session cookie value (if it exists) and sends it as a custom header in the request. This bypasses the normal CORS restrictions on cookies.

On the server side (in Firebase Functions), the Firebase runtime intercepts requests and looks for this custom header. If found, it reconstructs the __session cookie before passing the request to your function code.

This process is transparent to both your client-side and server-side code. You don't need to handle this cookie explicitly in most cases.

Despite not being sent as a normal cookie, the __session cookie is still protected against cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks because it's handled internally by the Firebase SDK.


This approach allows Firebase to maintain security while working around CORS restrictions that would otherwise prevent the cookie from being sent in cross-origin requests.

Next up for Custom Authentication Implementation you've following options I think:

You can try to use Firebase Custom Authentication to create custom tokens.

You can use Google Cloud Functions, it allow you to set custom headers for CORS, including Access-Control-Allow-Credentials. But it needs more manual configuration.

Lastly you can try VPS or NextJS/Vercel.


You can search for how to do that by mentioning the method on the web, but if it proves to be difficult, reach out to me, so I may be able to help out.

Good Luck 

Thank you so much for the response! So According to your answer, because the firebase authenticator library manages data internally and sends it via a header, this means that the authentication tokens and cookies must at some point be stored in javascript-accessible memory. But this would mean that it is xss vulnerable, although its probably hidden under many layers of obscurity (functions in functions in functions). Does this call into question if httponly cookie is even important and how prevalent xss is in this case? Share your thoughts!

Thanx for your insightful follow-up! You've raised a good point about the security implications of how Firebase handles authentication tokens. But let's see, while it's true that storing tokens in JavaScript-accessible memory could potentially expose them to XSS attacks, It has various security measures to mitigate such risks, including short-lived and frequently rotated encrypted tokens and careful handling of sensitive data. (It does that to increase the flexibility of token management across different contexts (web workers, service workers) where traditional cookies might not be accessible)

Of course I'm not denying the importance of HttpOnly Cookies in web security, to this day, if you're not using Firebase they remain a best practice for storing sensitive session information. But it also has it's own cons like every thing else, like it can be less flexible in modern web architectures (e.g., SPAs, PWAs). It may not always align well with token-based authentication systems, and if you are using third-party cookies and tracking prevention mechanisms in browsers can complicate traditional cookie-based approaches.

So in conclusion, while Firebase's approach does introduce some theoretical vulnerabilities, it also offers benefits in terms of flexibility and functionality. The key takeaway is that security is a multi-layered concern. Even if one layer (like HttpOnly cookies) is not present, other measures can compensate for it, like implementing strong Content Security Policies (CSP), regular security audits and penetration testing and a proper input sanitization and output encoding.
Ultimately, the importance of HttpOnly cookies hasn't diminished, but the landscape of web security is evolving.

Thank you for bringing up this topic. I think that it's discussions like these that help push our understanding of web security forward. I hope this was helpful to you even a little. Good Luck

Good points. I guess the most salient one is about how tokens are short lived. Although in my experience there are two flavors of "short lived" tokens, one that is approx. 30 mins to 1 hour which is meant to last long enough to finish your task, and one that it typically 10 minutes and requires frequent refresh for longer tasks. I do worry about the second kind since if an attacker can steal a refresh token then they can use it more permanently. I guess, in that case, the best way to do it is to associate each refresh token with a CSRF token.

Yes, this is an excellent approach, and it is called the "double submit cookie" pattern.

If this was helpful, please consider marking the answer correct or up voting it.
